# Using Visual Studio 2012 Express Version to reference dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I recently have been asked to write a .dll and some function that works with it. Since I've never touched this before, I would appologize if I asked something stupid.

First of all, my IDE is Visual Studio 2012 Express version.

On the other (green) hand, I follow the instructions at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.110).aspx to create projects.

I successfully built the dll project as adviced. The .dll file is peacefully lying in the `Debug` folder. However, when I create another project and try to reference to the .dll file that I created in the first project, at `Framework and References` page, I clicked `Add New Reference`, and no dll is found.

I am quite confused at this, since I've done everything the MSDN said. Thus I start to wonder if this is a limitation of Express version.

Can anyone clue me if I am on the right track?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions say

> The Add Reference dialog box lists the libraries that you can
>   reference. The Project tab lists the projects in the current solution
>   and any libraries that they contain. On the Projects tab, select the
>   check box next to MathFuncsDll, and then choose the OK button.

This means you add a reference to the dll *project* in the references section, not the dll that it produces.

Don't forget to link with the `.lib` file the dll project produces and give it a fighting chance of finding any header files you need to include, as per the instructions